flatpak dpkg issue : "Only one or two names allowed"
Hi everyone,
Last week update didn't go well for flatpak in a ubuntu 24.04 laptop :
Setting up flatpak (1.14.10-1~flatpak1~24.04.1) ...
fatal: Only one or two names allowed.
dpkg: error processing package flatpak (--configure)

I've tried to remove, reinstall, dpkg-reconfigure, added this flatpak repo from launchpad (which gives the 1.14 version), but to no avail. I've never seen this message before so I'm a bit in a loss in front of it.
Any idea I could try please ? For now I've removed it entirely because all updates are blocked because of this (but that's a poor workaround).

The flatpak version you cite in your output is not an Ubuntu-provided package. Uninstall it and disable the non-Ubuntu source that it came from. File a bug report with that upstream source. Try using the 1.14.6 package in the Ubuntu repositories.

I had this problem before adding the launchpad repo, which was an attempt to solve the issue. As it happens, removing the launchpad repo didn't help :
fatal: Only one or two names allowed.
dpkg: error processing package flatpak (--configure)```
Now I have the correct packages, but I still have the issue. I will look into filing a bug report, thanks.

This was indeed already reported as a bug :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flatpak/+bug/2083278
Solution explained at #4 (with provided patched package).
Worked for me.
